# Why the exception is not thrown if I create another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java-threads

I have a piece of code where an exception is thrown. The createStatus method from twitter4j library throws TwitterException, which extends Exception, so it's a checked exception.

```
private void simulateTwitterStream(
        String[] keywords, int minTweetLength, int maxTweetLength, long sleepTimeMs) throws TwitterException {

        while (true) {
            String formattedTweetAsRawJson = getFormattedTeet(keywords, minTweetLength, maxTweetLength);
            Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(formattedTweetAsRawJson);
            twitterKafkaStatusListener.onStatus(status);
            sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        }
}
```

After that I implemented the while loop in another thread like this:

```
private void simulateTwitterStream(
        String[] keywords, int minTweetLength, int maxTweetLength, long sleepTimeMs) {

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
        while (true) {
            String formattedTweetAsRawJson = getFormattedTeet(keywords, minTweetLength, maxTweetLength);
            Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(formattedTweetAsRawJson);
            twitterKafkaStatusListener.onStatus(status);
            sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        }
    });
}
```

But in this case, I don't need to use throws TwitterException at the method signature. Can somebody explain me why I don't need to use throws TwitterException.

Thank you

Comment: Because your method no longer throws the exception. The thread which may or may not run at any future point in time might encounter that exception but that no longer has any relation to your `simulateTwitterStream`.

Comment: Your code is now inside a Callable, which **does** declare that it can throw an exception. [Callable#call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--)

Comment: @khelwood thank you! but if the code is from call() which can throw Exception, then who catch it?

Comment: @elvis That's not your method's problem, because your method does not execute the Callable: It's the `Executor`'s problem.